# Duply profile not working with TARGET=ssh:// and ssh-options for identity file

Tags: openssh, duplicity

I have created a duply profile. I have tried several versions (all marked in the profile then commented) and nothing helps.
The script I launch to test the profile is the following :
bash -vvv /etc/cron.daily/duply
I run this script as root.
I have checked my public key in the /root/.ssh and used it to connect as root to the server and the key is accepted.

any help would be welcomed

````
GPG_KEY=disabled

SOURCE=/home/odile/Documents
TARGET=ssh://pcserveur@192.168.1.27://backup/backupdata_duply_odile/
#TARGET=pexpect+scp://pcserveur@192.168.1.27://backup/backupdata_duply_odile/
#the above line gives the following error message :
#dropped after 5 tries. BackendException: Error running 'sftp -oIdentityFile=~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub -oServerAliveInterval=15 -oServerAliveCountMax=2 pcserveur@192.168.1.27': Permission denied
#18:38:10.620 Task 'PURGE' failed with exit code '50'
MAX_AGE=2Y
MAX_FULLS_WITH_INCRS=2
MAX_FULLBKP_AGE=3M
#DUPL_PARAMS="$DUPL_PARAMS --full-if-older-than $MAX_FULLBKP_AGE "

# this is parameters for duplicity
#DUPL_PARAMS="$DUPL_PARAMS --ssh-options="-IdentityFile~/.ssh/id-rsa.pub\"" 
#DUPL_PARAMS="$DUPL_PARAMS --ssh-options "-i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"" 
#DUPL_PARAMS='$DUPL_PARAMS --ssh-options="-i~/.ssh/id-rsa"'
#DUPL_PARAMS="$DUPL_PARAMS --ssh-options "-i ~/.ssh/id_rsa""
#DUPL_PARAMS="$DUPL_PARAMS --ssh-options "-i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub""
#DUPL_PARAMS="$DUPL_PARAMS --ssh-options="-i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"" 
#error message for the above line
#/etc/duply/main/conf: ligne 23: /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub: Permission denied
#UnsupportedBackendScheme: scheme not supported in url: ssh://pcserveur@192.168.1.27://backup/backupdata_duply_odile/
#DUPL_PARAMS="$DUPL_PARAMS --ssh-options="-IdentityFile~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub""
#DUPL_PARAMS="$DUPL_PARAMS --ssh-options="-oIdentityFile='~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub'""
#DUPL_PARAMS="$DUPL_PARAMS --ssh-options="-oIdentityFile='~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub'" --use-scp"
# error message for the above line : unknown option --use-scp 
DUPL_PARAMS="$DUPL_PARAMS --ssh-options="-oIdentityFile='~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub'""
#error message for the above line :
#UnsupportedBackendScheme: scheme not supported in url: ssh://pcserveur@192.168.1.27://backup/backupdata_duply_odile/
#19:20:12.678 Task 'PURGE' failed with exit code '23'

VERBOSITY=DEBUG
ARCH_DIR=/var/cache/duplicity/duply_main/```
````

Comment: you need to use the **secret private key** for auth not the public key. make sure that you placed the public key to the remote machine beforehand e.g. with `ssh-copy-id`  see https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/SSH_keys#Simple_method

Comment: also better use `sftp://` as that is what the backend is actually using. `ssh://` is is just a legacy alias for old setups.

Comment: well thanks it works with sftp